# Read sensor data repeatedly after specified time?

Tags: arduino-mega, programming, interrupt, timers, atmega2560

I want to read sensor data using *analogRead()* after every 5ms. I have read other answers to similar questions but what I'm confused about is:

- let's say, I made a loop to read sensor data using *analogRead()* at the end of which I write *delay(50)*
- it means it'll take some time to read data(adc) , then it'll wait for 50ms
- time to execute loop isn't same for every iteration so we get the pattern as: *some time for loop execution*, *delay of 50ms*, *some time for next iteration*........and so on
  **I want to ask if I want arduino to read sensor data exactly every 5ms, what should I do?**
  Thanks

Comment: do not use delay() ..... see BlinkWithoutDelay  example sketch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store the time (`millis()`) of the last measurement. Then wait till 5ms have past since the last measurement. Do your measurement, and update the time.

Something like:

```
unsigned long lastMeasurement = millis();

void loop()
{
  while( (millis()-lastMeasurement)<5 ){/* do nothing */}
  lastMeasurement = lastMeasurement + 5; //or use `lastMeasurement=millis();` depending on whether you want accuracy between measurement, or accuracy over time
  auto measurement = analogRead(A0);
}
```

Comment: It waited for 5ms, then last measurement=0+5=5 ms. Then it’ll do analogRead().  Let’s say analogRead() took 10ms, then mills()- last measurement() = 15-5 ms=10 ms so the loop will do another analogRead() although it’s not reading measurement exactly after 5 ms. So this will only work if loop execution time is <5ms

Comment: Indeed. It can't magically go back in time. Was there any question there?

Answer (score 0):

You do something like this

```
unsigned long timerMesurement = 0;

void loop()
{
  if (millis() - timerMesurement > 5UL) { 
    timerMesurement = millis(); 
    int measurement = analogRead(A0); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Sigma, it should be `>=` for the right interval. It should also be `timermeasurement += 5UL;` for a interval that is fixed in time without increasing delays, the return value of millis() could have increased since the previous line.